# Move only .xls files not .xlsx, .xlsx, .xlsb

Tags: cmd

I'm looking to move only .xls files out of a directory (including subfolders) and not .xlsx or .xlsm files, I found a command that I thought would do the job and it works fine if I specify .xlsx and will only pull through files with that extension.

But when specifying .xls it pulls through .xls, .xlsx, .xlsm and .xlsb even though I don't have a trailing wildcard.

```
for /r "c:\source" %x in (*.xls) do move "%x" "c:\destination"
```

I'm not that familiar with this so I'm probably just missing something obvious but have tried a search and cannot find anything to resolve this issue.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: you can find the solution here [dir command: 3 and 4 char extensions are the same?](https://superuser.com/q/238900/241386)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*.xls` pattern is checked against both the long file names that are visible to the user and the short 8.3 file names that exist in the background by default and are intended for backwards compatibility. The short file names have extensions of 3 characters only, so a file with the long name `longfilename.xlsx` has a short file name extension `.xls`.

To overcome this behaviour, the easiest solution is to establish an additional filter by [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html):

```cmd
for /F "delims= eol=|" %x in ('dir /S /A:-D /B "C:\source\*.xls" ^| findstr /I "\.xls$"') do move "%x" "c:\destination"
```

Comment: Shorter alterenative solution:  

 for %g in (*.xls) do if /I "%~xg"==".xls" move "%g" "c:\destination"

Comment: Yes, @vitsoft, that should work, too (after re-adding the `/R` option to `for`); but I prefer to pre-filter the items so that the `for` loop only iterates the needed items; this might be a bit better in terms of performance in case of a lot of items...